# Is deleting secondary files a bad idea?

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

I have inherited a SQL DB that has 16 db files. All in the same filegroup of the 16 3 are set to grow the others are static consuming 1 GB each. Would there be a performance impact if I deleted the superfluous files. Should I do any re-indexing etc. afterwards?

Since this is on hold I'll try and be clearer though I believe the three gentlemen that responded have adequately answered my question. Thank you to them, all three responses have been helpful.

On the clarity issue the bottom line question is this. I have a DB that is made up of 16 files in the primary filegroup. They're on the same drive, in the same folder. 13 of the files make up less than 1% of the DB size. If I, following the proper procedure, delete them would there be likely be much of a performance impact (fragmentation etc.)

Thanks to all for the responses.

Comment: how do you know they are superfluous?  If they are empty will data be loaded into them again in the future?

Comment: Is this a very high frequency transactional environment at peak hours?  I ask because there's a small chance it was done to reduce logical file contention on the data files by having multiple GAM/SGAM returning requests.

Answer (score 3):

There are many considerations when determining the right number of files in a filegroup--Determining the proper number and layout of files in this filegroup is a separate question, but one that should not be ignored. File layouts for a database can be non-trivial, and the topic of adding/removing files from a filegroup raises lots of tangential discussion points.

That being said, I'm going to assume you've already looked at those things and come to the conclusion that you must remove some files.

If you choose to remove data files from a filegroup, the first step is to run `DBCC SHRINKFILE(logicalname,EMPTYFILE)`. (If you don't do this manually, the GUI will do it for you--I recommend against doing this sort of thing via the GUI.) This will evacuate data pages from this file and move them into another file in the filegroup that has room. This is done page-by-page, and is an online operation. However, just like any file-shrinking, it's going to cause all sorts of nasty fragmentation.

You probably want to run index maintenance after you remove the files.

Before you begin, you will  also want to consider which file(s) you want to remain at the end. I would go ahead and pre-grow those files so that you're not trying to autogrow FileA while trying to shrink FileB. Or possibly, I would just create some brand-new files and get rid of the existing 16 files.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely remove the secondary data files if you are absolutely sure that they provide no performance benefit as suggested.  To do this, as you may already know, you have to empty the file(s) and then delete it.  Once the file(s) is deleted, I would run your index maintenance job (rebuild or reorg) followed by a stats update to ensure no fragmentation exists and that the optimizer has the latest data about the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd not bother unless you have

- a seriously busy database (maybe at some peak) and multiple disk/SSD arrays
- or a very large database and multiple disk/SSD arrays

Multiple filegroups can distribute some load but often it is about recoverability with partial restores, read only filegroups etc

Transaction throughput is mostly determined by the log file anyway because of "Write Ahead Logging". Multiple secondary files add no value often. Remove them